# Why is my character jittering between walking and running in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

In my game, the character is able to blend in between 3 animations. if the magnitude is 0, then the character is idle, if the magnitude is 0.5, then the character is walking, and if the magnitude is 1 then the character is running.

And here is the base layer Animation Control Graph (The animations "Jump", "TakeStance" and "AimingSniperRifle" isn't currently being used): 
[image]

Here's the mentioned blend tree (inside of Idle Animation):
[image]

The difference between walking and running is that there is a speed cap titled AnimSpeedCap where based on if you are holding the run button (titled "TakeStance"), the cap would increase (So not pressing down the run button would set the cap to 0.5, but holding it down would set it to 1).

however, when testing the game, the character would always jitter in between the walking and running animations, even while the run button is held down. Why is this happening?

Code for running:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RunControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform StaminaBar;
    public GameObject BarPresent;
    private static float Stamina = 0.5f, MaxStamina = 0.5f;
    private bool StaminaIsRefilling = true;
    public bool isRunning = false;
    private float TimeCheck = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var RunSpeed = gameObject.GetComponent<PerspectiveControls>();

        if(Input.GetButton("TakeStance") && Stamina > 0 && isRunning == false)
        { //Running Code
            isRunning = true;
            RunSpeed.moveSpeed = 135f;
            RunSpeed.AnimSpeedCap = 1f;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Run");
            BarPresent.SetActive(true);
            StaminaIsRefilling = false;
            TimeCheck += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            RunSpeed.AnimSpeedCap = 0.5f;
            RunSpeed.moveSpeed = 35f;
            isRunning = false;
            StaminaIsRefilling = true;
            BarPresent.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (Stamina <= MaxStamina && StaminaIsRefilling == true && isRunning == false){Stamina += 0.025f; BarPresent.SetActive(false);} //Stamina Bar Refilling Code

        StaminaBar.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(Stamina/MaxStamina, 0.15f, 0.05f);

        if (TimeCheck >.50){TimeCheck = 0; Stamina -= 0.1f;} 
        if (Stamina < 0){Stamina = 0;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is your problem:

```
if(Input.GetButton("TakeStance") && Stamina > 0 && isRunning == false)
        { //Running Code
            isRunning = true;
```

Since you set isRunning to true, on the next update the `if` statement falls through to the `else` block, which in turn sets isRunning to false and the cycle continues.

Why do you need to check the isRunning flag in the RunningCode if statement?